# session time out when upload new code file

Tags: asp.net

Hey
I noticed that when I upload a new file code
For example: Class or aspx page
All sessions, expired, and all users are thrown out of the website
Is there a better way to update code?
Thanks in advance
Micah

Answer (score 1):

Uploading new files - especially web.config or classes in the App_Code folder will cause the App Pool to recycle and the code will recompile on the first request.

You can get away with updating CSS/JavaScript and even aspx files, but this is probably a situation where you should be 'closed for maintenance' - see [app_offline](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx)